# Mobile display different than desktop browser resolution

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm designing a website for both desktop and mobile use. Desktop looks like this (when window is sized down to mobile width):

[image]

but when I view it on my actual phone:

[image]

Why is there a discrepancy? Even using Google Chrome's dev tool, when I view it in different phone modes, it's rendering as it should with the text inside the box. I'm using standard CSS media queries with flexbox - it bothers me why it's displaying different results even though it's optimized.

```
<div className="products-overview-container">
    <h2>Product Categories</h2>
    <div className="products-overview-row-container">
        <div className="product-card">
            //Stuff goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.products-overview-container {
    margin: 80px 0px 30px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.products-overview-row-container {
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.product-card {
    margin: 50px 30px 30px 30px;
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .product-card {
        width: 95%,;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code....

Comment: Code added. It's just simple media queries.

Comment: can u try with `display: -webkit-flex;` for chrome & safari? & there are syntax error in media query .. it should be `@media screen and (max-width: 700px){}` like this

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my end. Where should I try adding `display: -webkit-flex`? Inside the media query?

Comment: check this: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp